# How can I find the missing information from openfda?

Tags: data.gov, api, openfda

I have performed adverse report based on drug name with male gender, unknown gender  and female gender and for all genders. But it seems like all genders count is not equal to the combined count of the female, male and unknown gender. It seems like age information is missing in some reports. So could someone please help me find the missing sex information, and why the counts do not add up, from openfda api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example,
[https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=*missing*:patient.patientsex+AND+patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:advil](https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=_missing_:patient.patientsex+AND+patient.drug.openfda.brand_name:advil)
and also please add up total reports=male(total) + female(total) + unknown(total) + missing(total). If you do it you might get the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Mike's answer:

You can use the the `_exists_:field_name` in the search parameter to see how many documents have a key. `_missing_:field_name` shows the documents that are missing that key. If you did a `count=field_name`, it should equal the total that you get in the meta field results for `_exists_:field_name`